# What is the purpose of the recurrence relation in low and high pass (audio) filters?

Tags: filters, audio, lowpass-filter, infinite-impulse-response, highpass-filter

Newbie here. I'm familiar with time and frequency domains from math. I *think* I understand what low and high pass filters do, sonically. But digging into an implementation of [`tone`](http://www.csounds.com/manual/html/tone.html) in csounds, I think I'm missing something fundamental. Take this description:

> A first-order recursive low-pass filter with variable frequency response.
>
> *tone* is a 1 term IIR filter. Its formula is:
>
> y<sub>n</sub> = c<sub>1</sub> * x<sub>n</sub> + c<sub>2</sub> * y<sub>n-1</sub>
>
> where
>
> - b = 2 - cos(2 π hp/sr);
> - c2 = b - sqrt(b<sup>2</sup> - 1.0)
> - c1 = 1 - c2

I see that there is a recurrence relation. But I'm reading about IIRs and filters in general I don't see any explanation of why it's there or what it does.

- Would performing a single pass of this formula not be considered performing a "true" low or high pass filter?
- Or is that it takes multiple passes (infinite, in theory) to completely "remove" the frequencies desiring to be removed, so it's a tradeoff between iterations versus computation?

I'm gravitating toward the latter, but I don't see where that is being said. Can someone point me to the essential statement of it on Wikipedia or somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IIR filter is a **recursive** one. It means, current value of output $y[n]$ is computed based on its previous value(s).

Consider a simple 1st order IIR filter definition:

$$y[n] = a \cdot y[n-1]+ b \cdot x[n]$$

$a$ and $b$ are the filter coefficients.

Now assume you have a long block of N samples input data. If you want to process that block of input data with this filter, you can do it like in this matlab code :

```
N = 1024;       % number of input samples
x = randn(N,1); % some random input.
a = 0.5;        % IIR filter coefficients
b = 0.9;

yi = 0;         % initial value for output
y = zeros(N,1); % matrix (array) to hold processed output samples

y(1) = a*yi + b*x(1)   % assign first output sample based on y(-1) 
for n=2:N              % assign rest
    y(n) = a*y(n-1) + b*x(n);
end
```

Comment: Yes, but _why_? I guess to anyone in the field it might sound like I'm asking, _"Why does addition work?"_ Maybe I'm asking: How is the sound changing in each iteration? Is it improving the filtering? How is it determined how many iterations to compute, since obviously we can't compute infinity?

Comment: Oh, maybe your code does clarify things. Is it doing a pass over the input samples in _time_, _e.g._ `y(t)`? So a previous calculation in time is affecting the next?

Comment: Yes, that's why I put the code to clarify it. Your second comment catches it: previous value of output affect the current value. And that's the reason why it's called *recurrent*, in addition to *recursive*, *iterative* etc.. Note however that, this recursive filtering is not similar to an **successive approximation** iteration, in which a target value is gradually perfected at each iteration and then terminated when it's sufficiently  close to desired value... No they are unrelated. We are not doing an approximation loop here.

Comment: Ah, "successive approximation" is exactly what I thought it was doing. And I thought that because it felt unbelievable to me that an algorithm can remove frequencies in a single pass over the time domain... but apparently it can. That's crazy.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Yes it can.. ;-) Lowpass, highpass, bandpass all work on a single pass over the duration of the signal block...

Comment: Thanks. In case anyone else comes by this question, here's [another question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41854/low-pass-filter-algorithm-origin) with more information. This comment by @RobertBristowJohnson in particular: _"i think if there is any "ontological" origin to the low-pass filter, i think it would lie with the concept of the arithmetic mean. we do averaging to "filter out" variations and to leave a general trend."_

Comment: @AndrewCheong yes that's a good question and so is this answer [link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31161/why-do-digital-filters-work/31165#31165)

Comment: Holy crap, I can't wait to read all these. Thanks very much. I would even say that it's valid to close this question as a duplicate of that last one. I just didn't know how to ask what I was confused about.

Comment: No problem, this question had a specific concern about a particular IIR filter, whereas the other was a more general one. Yes there are so many links to read ;-)